# How to set DNS with Google Domains and Vultr?

Tags: google, web-hosting, dns, domain-registrar

I moved my domain from GoDaddy to [Google Domains](https://domains.google.com) and the hosting to [VULTR](https://www.vultr.com/). I used BIND9 when it was registered on GoDaddy and hosted on Vultr. I am not sure how to proceed with setting up the domain when its registered with Google Domains and hosted with VULTR.

The server it chose on VULTR is Debian 8 x64 (jessie). The Main IP address is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. When I got to the IPv4 tab, it shows me:

1. Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
2. Netmask: 255.255.254.0
3. Gateway: xxx.xxx.xxx.1
4. Reverse DNS: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.vultr.com

IPv6 is not currently available.

On Google Domains, I chose to use Google's name servers:

1. ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com
2. ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com
3. ns-cloud-d3.googledomains.com
4. ns-cloud-d4.googledomains.com

Comment: Doesn't Vulr have tech support AND a forum for these questions? Well, by golly, they have both! How 'bout that.

Comment: What specifically do you need help with?? For example, do you need to know *how* to with Google Domains but you know *what* to set? Or is it you know that there is a control panel to use, but not sure what DNS records you need? I do not know Google Domains, but can help with DNS records in general if you know their interface.

Comment: Yes. But I am not sure what goes where. I followed this tutorial: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/perfect-server-debian-8-jessie-apache-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3/3/ and it seems to work. For the VULTR DNS I followed this: https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-your-own-dns-server-on-debian-ubuntu ... I did not get anything when refreshing my domain name - until after I setup the squirellmail program. But now when I go to www.mydomain.com it load the sqirellmail. How can I change that to show my index.php